# Is it possible to develop iphone, ipad apps using ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode

Usually apple developers use Mac to develop there apps for iphone and ipad. I need to know whether it is possible to develop the same apps using ipad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to build an iPad app on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425785/is-it-possible-to-build-an-ipad-app-on-the-ipad)

Comment: Sometimes I wish I had more than two 22" screens. And you want to develop on an iPad? :-)

Answer (score 4):

No you can't, there is no SDK and XCode running on iOS (yet).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. You need XCode for development, which is Mac-only.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is not available for the iPad, so I would say practically no at this point.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. Xcode and the iOS SDK is only available for the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

No.There is no XCode or ios SDK for ipad only.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through some forums, it appears it's not possible and unlikely to happen anytime soon...

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=856312

http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/ipad-hardware-accessories/196910-xcode-ipad.html

Apple's XCode is only available on Mac, for a beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Basically NO you can't... you can not compile the app on iPad/iPhone. But think in other way.. do you want to give this functionality to your app users right? then.. you can do one thing.. you can create a template of project which will run using a xml file. you can create this xml file on iPad/iPhone using some interface. (like putting a button on area and set its color). Then you can send this xml file on server. Here you can manually put this xml file in your template project and can compile the app manually on your system. Then you can submit this app to app store for your app users. You can charge them for this.

This is something similar to http://mobileroadie.com/ but on iPad